# Simplest way to create busy animation in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, components, busyindicator

I mentioned that there is no standard busy control in WPF. So what's the easiest way to display animated busy circle (not progress bar) such as your browser displays when loading a page ?

Please if you suggest downloading control from internet make sure that this control is for free and with no licence restriction (such as I would be forced to GPL my application if I use it).

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[BizzySpinner 2 – A WPF Spinning Busy State Indicator (with source)](http://foredecker.wordpress.com/2010/01/11/bizzyspinner-2-a-wpf-spinning-busy-state-indicator-with-source/)

Comment: licence is Microsoft Public License

Comment: How do I add this control to my toolbox ?

Answer (score 19):

There's also Sacha Barber's [Circular Progress Bar](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/49853/Better-WPF-Circular-Progress-Bar). It's licensed under the Code Project Open License.

Comment: Probably moved to http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/49853/Better-WPF-Circular-Progress-Bar

Comment: Someone in the comments on that page made a no-code-behind version. it's pretty slick. Direct link: http://fredgrass.blogspot.com/2015/07/wpf-busy-indicator.html

Answer (score 10):

You can also use animated gifs, compare e.g. this site: http://www.loadinfo.net/. Different colors, forms, frames per second, transparant background are generated for you.

Then you add the [WPF Animated GIF](https://wpfanimatedgif.codeplex.com/) as a reference to your project.

Make a usercontrol with `<Image gif:ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource="Images/animated.gif" />` as its content and give the usercontrol a dependencyproperty (DP) `IsBusy` with a callback to a method in the usercontrol:

```
`public static readonly DependencyProperty IsBusyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsBusy", typeof(bool), typeof(SpinProgress), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnIsBusyChangedCallBack)));`
```

In this method the animated gif's `Play()` and 'Pause()' methods can be executed.
Bind the usercontrol's `IsBusy` property to the view-model.

Or - when appropiate - ignore the DP and the `Play()` and `Pause()` methods and bind the `Visibility` property to the view-model.

Answer (score 4):

You can implement processing wheel while your application is busy. although WPF do not support any GIF images so you've to use animation for this. below is a good link for FrameAnimation spin wheel.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29545/FrameBasedAnimation-Animating-multiple-properties

Answer (score 3):

I recently uploaded one to codeplex. It allows you to customize it (even in runtime). You can download it from [here](http://spinningwheel.codeplex.com). Sample demo also uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

I recently implemented one that looks like the iPhone busy indicator, explained [here](http://eersonmez.blogspot.com/2011/12/wpf-busy-indicator.html).

Comment: Rotates a png file.  Not actually drawing.  Which, to me, takes away the advantage of WPF where everything is drawn and looks smooth at any scaling.

Comment: @ClintStLaurent Not everything has to be vector based in WPF. In this case, imaging is simpler to implement and as a bonus, it is more efficient than vector graphics.  However, the main point of this technique was changing the animation rate in order to make the visual look "static". So you can certainly 1) pick a different image sized for your use case, 2) swap out the Image with a Path if you'd like. Same technique would still apply.